# Как склоняется фамилия Шолина?

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Answer (score 1):

Мужская склоняется по обычным правилам. Шолина, Шолины, Шолине... Как жемчужина или смородина.
Если это фамилия женская, то надо смотреть на её мужской вариант.
Если мужской вариант - тоже Шолина, то женская склоняется как мужская.
А если мужская Шолин, то по правилам женских фамилий на "-ина": Шолина, Шолиной... Шолину... Как Мишина или Васина.